# with SFTP - how to cd and lcd with one command?

Tags: sftp

I'm using SFTP via terminal to connect to a server to upload and download files.  I often find myself typing statements like this:

```
cd website/theme/drupal7default/assets/css
lcd website/theme/drupal7default/assets/css
put mainstyle.css
```

It would be much better if I could have one command that can perform both a cd and lcd.  So that I can do something like:

```
cdboth website/theme/drupal7default/assets/css
put mainstyle.css
```

This will make sure my lpwd and pwd are the same.  Does the command I'm looking for exist?  And if the command does exist, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `sftp` the easiest way is probably to use the <kbd>⇧</kbd> arrow to return to previous command, then <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line, then <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That is:

- <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

For your use case perhaps the internal SFTP client is not the smoothest way, though. You don't mention OS, but if it concerns *nix, then using an **SCP wrapper script** directly might be a simple way to save time in the end, creating e.g. `myupload` and `mydownload` that attempts to upload or download the file given as argument to/from the server respectively, automatically deciding the correct paths from some given base project paths. Set up key based login so you don't have to enter a password every time.

Another pro with using **SCP from the command line** on *nix as compared to the SFTP client is that you will be in a familiar shell environment, most likely Bash, and have access to regular navigation tricks among the commands such as tab completion, command repetition, brace expansion, etc.

Personally I prefer **version control systems** for these kinds of tasks. It will give you simple uploading using e.g. a commit hook, and version control is very handy for code projects. I don't know exactly what you are doing so it might not fit perfectly, but if you like, take a look at e.g. [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: I agree with everything you said.  Their systems admin disabled my ssh access.  I think that's why when i run scp command, i get permission error.  This system hasn't installed version contorl yet.